# Semi Definite Test of a Matrix:

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

I have a problem. My linear algebra course pack says that there is no simple test to check whether a matrix is positive or negative semi-definite. But my mathematical economics course-pack says.

1. A is positive semi definite if and only if every principle minor of A is non-negative.
2. And A is negative semi-definite if and only if every principle minor of order is non-positive and every principal minor of even order is non-negative.

My Mathematical course pack specifically references Symmetric Matrices? So perhaps the test is valid only when our matrix is symmetric?

Indeed I have many cases in my course where $a_{11} < 0$ and $|H| = 0$ and we say it's NSD.

However this line from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#:%7E:text=In%20one%20variable%2C%20the%20Hessian,then%20the%20test%20is%20inconclusive.) Hessian page, is also confusing me, as I assumed the Hessian would always be symmetric...at least in the usual cases where the mixed second partials are =

> *The second-derivative test for functions of one and two variables is simpler than the general case. In one variable, the Hessian contains exactly one second derivative; if it is positive, then $x$ is a local minimum, and if it is negative, then
> $x$ is a local maximum; if it is zero, then the test is inconclusive. **In two variables, the determinant can be used**, because the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. If it is positive, then the eigenvalues are both positive, or both negative. If it is negative, then the two eigenvalues have different signs. **If it is zero, then the second-derivative test is inconclusive.***

For reference I have attached a highlighted screenshot of each course pack, thanks!:

[image]

[image]